# Positioning JPanels with GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing

Iam trying to set GUI consisted of two JPanels and one JMenuBar using GridBagLayout.
Right now it looks like :

[image]

I would like to display it some like this:

[image]

(Unfortunately i cant post images because of not enough reputation)

I have tried different GridbagConstraints settings but i cant achieve that.

Is it possible with GridBagLayout that components will have the same size when main frame will grow smaller and on the other hand components will fill the frame when it grows?

**DisplayClass**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints; 
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DisplayClass extends JFrame {

JPanel tabPanel;
JPanel rightPanel;
JMenuBar menu;
JPanel textPanel; 

public DisplayClass()
{
    textPanel =  TextPanel.getTextPanel();
    rightPanel = RightPanel.getRightPanel();;
    tabPanel = TabbedPane.getTabbedPane();

    this.getContentPane().add(setContent());
    this.setLocation(0, 0);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(1000, 700);
    this.setVisible(true);  
}

public static void main(String args[]) 
{         
    DisplayClass frame = new DisplayClass();
    MainMenu menu = MainMenu.getMainMenu();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menu.createJMenuBar());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

private  Container setContent()
{
         JPanel content = new JPanel();
      content.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints g = new GridBagConstraints();        

      g.gridx = 0;
      g.gridy = 0;
      g.gridwidth = 1;
      g.gridheight = 1;
      g.ipadx = 10;
      g.ipady = 3;
      g.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
      g.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
      g.weightx = 1;
      g.weighty = 1;
      content.add(tabPanel, g);

      g.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
      g.gridx = 1;
      g.gridy = 0;
      g.gridwidth = 1;
      g.gridheight = 1;
      g.ipadx = 10;
      g.ipady = 3;
      content.add(rightPanel, g);

      return content;
}
}
```

**RightPanel**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;   
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;   

public class RightPanel extends JPanel
{
private JLabel charLabel;
private JTextField letterCount;
private JTextField charField;
private GridBagConstraints g;
private JButton replaceButton;


private RightPanel()
{
    this.setSize(800, 700);
    this.setKomponents();
}


private void setKomponents(){

  this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
  g = new GridBagConstraints();


  char letter = 'A';

  for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) 
  {   
          charLabel = new JLabel(String.valueOf(letter)); 
          g.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
          g.gridx = 0;
          g.gridy = i;
          g.ipadx = 10;
          g.ipady = 3;
         // g.anchor = g.FIRST_LINE_END;
          this.add(charLabel, g);

          charField = new JTextField(String.valueOf(letter)); 
          g.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
          g.gridx = 1;
          g.gridy = i;
          g.ipadx = 10;
          g.ipady = 3;
          charField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
          this.add(charField, g);

          letterCount = new JTextField(String.valueOf(letter)); 
          letterCount.setEditable(false);
          letterCount.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
          g.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
          g.gridx = 2;
          g.gridy = i;
          g.ipadx = 10;
          g.ipady = 3;
          this.add(letterCount, g);

          letter++;          
}
  replaceButton = new JButton("Replace"); 
  g.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
  g.gridx = 0;
  g.gridy = 27;
  g.gridheight = 1;
  g.gridwidth = 3;
  g.ipadx = 3;
  g.ipady = 3;
   this.add(replaceButton, g);   
}

public static JPanel getRightPanel(){

 return new RightPanel();
}  
}
```

**TabbedPanel**

```
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.BorderLayout; 
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class TabbedPane extends JPanel 
{
private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
private TabbedPane() 
{    
    super(new GridLayout(1, 1));

     this.tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

     this.createPage1();
     this.createPage2();
     this.createPage3();
     this.createPage4();

    add(tabbedPane);

    //The following line enables to use scrolling tabs.
    //tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
}

public static JPanel getTabbedPane()
{
    return new TabbedPane();
}


void createPage1()
{
    JPanel panel1 = TextPanel.getTextPanel();
     this.tabbedPane.addTab("Main", panel1);
     this.tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_2);  
}


void createPage2()
{
    double values [] = new double [3];
    values [0] = 3;
    values [1] = 6;
    values [2] = 15;
    String names [] =  {"a","b","c"};


     JPanel panel2 = UnigramPanel.getUnigramPanel(values, names, "Unigram graph");
     this.tabbedPane.addTab("tab1", panel2);
     this.tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(1, KeyEvent.VK_2);
}

void createPage3()
{
    double values [] = new double [3];
    values [0] = 3;
    values [1] = 6;
    values [2] = 15;
    String names [] =  {"a","b","c"};


     JPanel panel3 = UnigramPanel.getUnigramPanel(values, names, "Bigram graph");
     this.tabbedPane.addTab("tab2", panel3);
     this.tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(1, KeyEvent.VK_2);
}


void createPage4()
{
    double values [] = new double [3];
    values [0] = 3;
    values [1] = 6;
    values [2] = 15;
    String names [] =  {"a","b","c"};


     JPanel panel4 = UnigramPanel.getUnigramPanel(values, names, "Trigram graph");
     this.tabbedPane.addTab("tab3", panel4);
     this.tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(1, KeyEvent.VK_2);
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TabbedPaneDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.add(getTabbedPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);    

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();  
    frame.setVisible(true);
} 
}
```

**TextPanel**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*; 

public class TextPanel extends JPanel
{
private BufferedReader input;
private String line;
private JFileChooser fileChoser;
private final JTextArea textArea;
private JButton openFileButton;
private JButton saveFileButton;
private JButton countButton;

private TextPanel()
{
  line = new String();
  fileChoser = new JFileChooser(); 
  this.textArea = new JTextArea(30, 60);   
  this.displayGUI();
}


public static JPanel getTextPanel(){

     return new TextPanel();
  }

public void displayGUI()
{
  textArea.setLineWrap(true);  
  textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);  

  this.openFileButton = new JButton("OPEN FILE");
  this.openFileButton.addActionListener(new ALOpenFileButton());
  this.saveFileButton = new JButton("SAVE FILE");
  this.saveFileButton.addActionListener(new ALSaveFileButton());
  this.countButton = new JButton("button");
  this.countButton.addActionListener(new ALCountButton());

  this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());     
  GridBagConstraints g = new GridBagConstraints();

  g.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
  g.gridx = 0;
  g.gridy = 0;
  g.gridwidth = 2;
  g.ipadx = 10;
  g.ipady = 3; 
  this.add(textArea, g);

  JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( this.textArea );
  g.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
  g.gridx = 1;
  g.gridy = 0;
  g.gridwidth = 0;
  this.add(scrollPane,g);


  g.gridx = 0;
  g.gridy = 1;
  g.ipadx = 10;
  g.ipady = 3;
  g.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
  g.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST;
  this.add(openFileButton, g);


  g.gridx = 1;
  g.gridy = 2;
  g.ipadx = 10;
  g.ipady = 3;
  g.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
  g.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST;
  this.add(saveFileButton, g);   

  g.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
  g.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST;
  g.gridx = 2;
  g.gridy = 1;
  g.ipadx = 10;
  g.ipady = 3;
  this.add(countButton, g);   
}

private class ALOpenFileButton implements ActionListener
{

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
   {         
     FileOperations file = FileOperations.getFileOperations();
     file.openFile(textArea, fileChoser);
   }
}

private class ALSaveFileButton implements ActionListener
{

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
 {
     FileOperations file = FileOperations.getFileOperations();
     file.saveFile(textArea, fileChoser);


 }
}

private class ALCountButton implements ActionListener
{

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
 {
      FrequentAnalysis fa = FrequentAnalysis.getFrequentAnalysis();
      //String unigramCount = fa.countUnigrams(textArea);
      int[] unigramCount = fa.countUnigrams(textArea);
      int[][] bigramCount = fa.countBigrams(textArea);
      int[][][] trigramCount = fa.countTrigrams(textArea);

      textArea.append((Integer.toString(trigramCount[0][0][0])));
 }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> super(new GridLayout(1, 1));

Don't use a GridLayout, it will make all components an equal size.

I would probably use a `BorderLayout`. Add the main panel to the `CENTER` (so it can grow/shrink as the space available changes) and the secondary panel to the `EAST` (it will remain a fixed size).

Answer (score 0):

GridBagLAyout is really difficult to get right.

It is almost always easier to achieve what you want by nesting panels inside each other using BorderLayout and possibly a few of the other basic layouts.

BorderLayout will always try to expand the center element as much as possible, shrinking the contents along the edges (north, south, east, west).

The buttons ("open file" etc) on the bottom, should be added to a jpanel with a rudimentary layoutmanager such as FlowLayout. That panel should then be added to the main panel in position SOUTH (given you use borderLayout). The panel with all the letters should similarily be added at position EAST. Finally, the main text panel can be added in CENTER. Swing will then try to expand the CENTER part as much as possible, and compact the SOUTH and EAST parts as much as reasonable.